# Is it "he" or "him" in the sentence?

Tags: pronouns, coordination, case

I read a sentence in a news paper and it was like

> Abhinav Bindra's final Olympics finished in the most agonising manner when the Indian shooter lost out in a shootout after both **him** and Serhiy Kulish of Ukraine were tied at 163.8 after seven series of shots.

Does **him** right here?

I think **he** is right since it is referring to the subject here.

Correct me if I'm wrong.

Is it wrong to use **he** instead of **him**?

Please explain to me.

Comment: Yes, this is an error in _case_. The phrase _he and Serhiy Kulish_ is the subject of the verb _were tied_ in the clause. The correct pronoun is **he**, which is the _subjective_ case. _Him_ is the _objective_ case.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Standard English requires the pronoun to be *he* there as it is functioning as part of the subject of its clause. So you are correct.

You might sometimes hear *him* used as a subject pronoun in informal spoken English, but this would still be considered ungrammatical according to standard English.